# Why isn't my display language setting working everywhere with the VS Code Cpptools extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the Win 10 in with PL language set but for IDEs, tools etc. I'm using the ENG. In the Visual Studio Code I have the English selected, I have no other language packs installed but in some places I see some comments in Polish - maybe the VSCode uses some settings from the system. Is possible to change it?

Settings and the problem shown:
[image: screen]

---

Update:

Some important information - I'm using additional extensions:

- C/C++ Extension Pack (by MS)
- Arduino for Visual Studio Code (by MS)

Now let's see again the initial problem:
[image: problem]

After changing the preferred language in the system:
[image: almost no problem]

I checked the topic - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/82791
Looks like it's working but not. To be more precise - yes and no.

Short TODO:

- C:\Users****.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.14.4-win32-x64\dist\main.js
- go to function initializeSettings (line 76474)

This is part of the src with few extra lines (+ comment at the end of line):

```
    if (isString(process.env.VSCODE_NLS_CONFIG)) {
    console.error(process.env.VSCODE_NLS_CONFIG)//added
    try {
        var vscodeOptions_1 = JSON.parse(process.env.VSCODE_NLS_CONFIG);
        var language = void 0;
        if (vscodeOptions_1.availableLanguages) {
            var value = vscodeOptions_1.availableLanguages['*'];
            if (isString(value)) {
                language = value;
            }
        }
        if (isString(vscodeOptions_1.locale)) {
            options.locale = vscodeOptions_1.locale.toLowerCase();
        }
        if (language === undefined) {
            options.language = options.locale;
            console.error("undefined");//added
            options.language = "en";//added
        }
        else if (language !== 'en') {
            options.language = language;
        }
```

This is the output in the VS Code:

[image: out]

so the locale is "pl" but we have no available languages visible and we're entering the undefinded case. After modification the "en" should be forced.
But the result is not fully acceptable:

[image: res]

MAYBE three last messages are handled by different extension - I have no other idea.

I set the English (US) as the preferred system language - the only difference in the process.env.VSCODE_NLS_CONFIG is "locale" : "en-us"

Unfortunately in the vsciot-vscode.vscode-arduino-0.5.0-win32-x64 I see no VSCODE_NLS_CONFIG usage.

Comment: can you please add a transcription of the text instead of just an image? And what happens if you change your system language to english?

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into a bug. Others have run into similar. See this discussion on the VS Code Cpptools extension's Github: [How do I change language of messages?
#9192](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/discussions/9192).

[A user named wine-fall commented there](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/discussions/9192#discussioncomment-3616934) that they were able to fix the problem by doing the following:

> 1. go to `Configure Display Language`
> 2. change the language to your native language
> 3. change the language back to English

As indicated in the comments, you had success by adding english as a system language and giving it priority. I'd encourage you to report that behaviour to the vscode-cpptools maintainers either in a discussion thread, or as an issue ticket. You could use the existing one I first linked to.

Other related issue tickets and PRs include:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/9929
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/82791
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/10632
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4600

For your reference, those are search results from googling "`github issues vscode cpptools change language`".

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. After changing to the PL, everything was in the Plish, after changing back to ENG - i got the same content visible at the beginning.

Comment: I checked another thing - in the Windows - language settings. I added 2nd language - ENG US. After setting it as the preferred language for the applications, I got the English content everywhere in the VS. But after changing the prio of the language - to the PL on the 1st place, I'm going back to the problem - English GUI  with Polish comments/problems descriptions etc.
I didn't notice the change in the "locale": "en" line in the argv.json file - it's still "en".

Comment: @sprzatacz I edited to take into account your findings.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.